# How we make unit test code of wcf calling method using shim

Tags: c#, wcf, unit-testing, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a method of wcf calling in xamarin and want to create the test code of this method using shim fake

```
    public Dictionary<int, string> GetProductCategory()
    {
        BasicHttpBinding binding = AceWCFBinding.CreateBasicHttp();
        using ( AceWCFClientWrapper<AceVqbzServiceClient> objAceWCFClientWrapper = new AceWCFClientWrapper<AceVqbzServiceClient>( binding, AceWCFBinding.EndPoint ) )
        {
            IAceVqbzService aceVqbzTypeService = objAceWCFClientWrapper._proxy as IAceVqbzService;
            var _task = Task<Dictionary<int, string>>.Factory.FromAsync( aceVqbzTypeService.BeginGetProductCategory, aceVqbzTypeService.EndGetProductCategory, TaskCreationOptions.None );
            Dictionary<int, string> _res = _task.Result;
            return _res;
        }
    }
```

Please provide me the way how i will manage the test code of this method

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want to test:

1. GetProductCategory() method doesn't have any logic. It simply fetch data from webservice. For me there is nothing to test.
2. If you want to fake result dictionary then simply mark method as virtual and override GetProductCategory in custom class(or using Moq, NSubstitute..) and implement it to return your custom dictionary. [this solution drag dependencies to wcf client]
3. If you don't want to drag dependencies to WCF client then extract interface with method GetProductCategory. Then decorate current class with it. For testing purpose you can now create mock, stubs etc based on this interface.